# What's the best and smallest framework for flex 4?

Tags: frameworks, flex4, mate, robotlegs, swiz

I'm looking for a framework that is small and reliable and works in Flex 4. 
I have some suggestions (but which should I choose):

**[Mate](http://mate.asfusion.com/)**

**[swiz framework](http://swizframework.org/)**

**[robotlegs](http://www.robotlegs.org/)**

Comment: You might find better success asking more specific questions about the frameworks; this is really open-ended.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not entirely sold on frameworks either.

Comment: what do you need the framework for? frameworks are not silver bullets

Comment: Kind of thought they would help when the application gets bigger.. But I don't really know..

Answer (score 1):

Parsley is another choice that is well documented and can be used in a very lightweight manner. I'm partial to Robotlegs personally, as I like that it is very tiny as a framework and most of the broader functionality is provided by the community through extensions and add-ons.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I've used [Mate](http://mate.asfusion.com/) on several fairly large projects and must say it works quite well. I personally found it easier to learn and use than Cairngorm.

Property injection alone has made developing some of these projects a lot cleaner/smoother/faster. If I had to choose whether to use Mate on a project or go without a framework at all, I'd choose Mate every time.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working for years on a project that is correspondingly huge.  I've used Mate as the core framework of this project, and love it.  I have found it to be just enough for what I need.  I get the features I want without dramatically changing the design of my project.  Contrast that with Cairgorm where your project becomes a complete frankenstein that doesn't remotely resemble how your project would look without it.

I have years of MVC experience (mostly Java Struts, *shudder*) and dependency injection experience (Spring, Guice, etc).  As mentioned, I've also dealt with Cairgorm and found it to be one of the most painful experiences of my entire career.  Out of the MVC and DI frameworks I've dealt with, Mate is the one I've enjoyed the most.  I have no experience with Robotlegs or Swiz, so I can't directly compare them.

The only knock I would give against Mate is that it does not seem to be very actively maintained these days.  However, I find it to be very bug free, and not in much need of maintenance.  It isn't broke, and doesn't need much fixing.

Answer (score -1):

All three are solid frameworks and I know very talented and seasoned developers who are partial to one or the other for various reasons.

All three have a dependency injection mechanism built into them and that is the sweet spot.

Mate is by far the most lightweight since it focuses primarily on dependency injection. Robotlegs and Swiz are a little more full featured and have more MVC components built into it.

So to that, I agree with Jason.

Comment: Swiz does not include a MVC component. Robotlegs does but as far as I know it's optional.